# deleting sms from inbox

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am developing an android SMS app where I am deleting messages based on _id using below code:

```
 getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id),"address=? and date=?",null);
```

This is working fine on some phones. But on Samsung phones the oldest message is getting deleted. And I don't want that to happen. I want to delete particular Sms on touch. How can I do it?